# Unable to link QwtPlot3d in project

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, qwt

I am using in my C++ project QwtPlot3d and GCC 4.6 with `-D_GLIBCXX_PROFILE` flag. When my project tried to link, I get the error message:

```
 undefined reference to Qwt3D::MeshPlot::createDataset(std::__profile::vector<Qwt3D::Triple,
 std::allocator<Qwt3D::Triple> > const&, 
std::__profile::vector<std::__profile::vector<unsigned int,
std::allocator<unsigned int> >, 
std::allocator<std::__profile::vector<unsigned int, 
std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > const&, bool)
```

Any suggestions?